# Как сделать автоматическую смену высоты textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать автоматическую смену высоты textarea без использования библиотек.

Comment: https://stephanwagner.me/auto-resizing-textarea. Но с использованием jquery

Answer (score 0):

Первая ссылка в google по запросу "textarea auto height" - https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/czgrf

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

textarea.addEventListener('keydown', autosize);

function autosize() {
  var el = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    el.style.cssText = 'height:auto; padding:0';
    // for box-sizing other than "content-box" use:
    // el.style.cssText = '-moz-box-sizing:content-box';
    el.style.cssText = 'height:' + el.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }, 0);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #728EB2;
  color: #FFF;
}


/*( 'box-sizing' will not work with this code )*/

textarea {
  /* box-sizing: padding-box; */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* demo only: */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 6px solid #556677;
}
```

```html
<p>This solution is OBSOLETE, checkout my better solution - <a href='https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/frudD' target='_blank'>https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/frudD</a>

  <textarea rows='1' placeholder='Auto-Expanding Textarea'></textarea>
```

Comment: Попробуйте вводить много текст (больше высоты ввода), смешно однако получается))

Comment: Хотя бы копипаст нормальный делал бы)) `This solution is OBSOLETE, checkout my better solution - <a href='https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/frudD'`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я специально скопировал полностью. Если автор оригинального решения предлагает лучший вариант - почему нет? Плюс этим ответом я больше хотел показать, что гуглом полоьзоваться не так сложно, нежели чем дать человеку "рыбку"

Comment: @ИванmalginovdesignМальгинов как думаешь, этот сайт существует, чтоб его посылали в гугл или гугл существует, чтоб узнавать решение тут?

Comment: @ИванmalginovdesignМальгинов ссылка на стороннем сайте может перестать работать со временем, поэтому ответ должен содержать решение, а не ссылку на другой сайт.